# How to add a vendor with composer using commit

Tags: laravel, composer-php

How can i add this commit to my composer.json file?

https://github.com/fitztrev/laravel-html-minify/commit/d9b75c493eee593bb4e1622220e95c5783409635

```
"require-dev": {
  "fitztrev/laravel-html-minify": "dev-master#d9b75c493eee593bb4e1622220e95c5783409635"
}
```

This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this in composer it says that the hash you are trying to clone no longer exists or was rewritten. Going back through the commit history this is not a commit that is on the master branch. This is why the error is happening.

Comment: So, is it possible use pull request with composer?

Comment: No, composer is for managing packages and automating installations. So you could install a previous commit. Git is used for pull requests.